# Leaflet - Hiding labels when any popup window is shown?

Tags: leaflet, labeling, popup

I am new to Leaflet and have found the following solution to add static labels to features in my map:

```
L.CircleMarker.include({
    bindLabel: function (content, options) {
        if (!this._label || this._label.options !== options) {
            this._label = new L.Label(options, this);
        }

        this._label.setContent(content);
        this._labelNoHide = options && options.noHide;

        if (!this._showLabelAdded) {
            if (this._labelNoHide) {
                this
                    .on('remove', this.hideLabel, this)
                    .on('move', this._moveLabel, this);
                this._showLabel({latlng: this.getLatLng()});
            } else {
                this
                    .on('mouseover', this._showLabel, this)
                    .on('mousemove', this._moveLabel, this)
                    .on('mouseout remove', this._hideLabel, this);
                if (L.Browser.touch) {
                    this.on('click', this._showLabel, this);
                }
            }
            this._showLabelAdded = true;
        }

        return this;
    },

    unbindLabel: function () {
        if (this._label) {
            this._hideLabel();
            this._label = null;
            this._showLabelAdded = false;
            if (this._labelNoHide) {
                this
                    .off('remove', this._hideLabel, this)
                    .off('move', this._moveLabel, this);
            } else {
                this
                    .off('mouseover', this._showLabel, this)
                    .off('mousemove', this._moveLabel, this)
                    .off('mouseout remove', this._hideLabel, this);
            }
        }
        return this;
    }
});


L.marker([-37.7772, 175.2606]).bindLabel('Look revealing label!').addTo(map);
```

The thing is that if the label is too big the labels are displayed above the popup window, not behind.

[image]

I don't know how to hide those labels when the popup appears?

Comment: Are you using your own element (such as a DIV) as a popup or is it a Leaflet popup?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do a simple css trick on popup open .
I am assuming you used jquery if not change the code accordingly, While adding label add them in a particular class and then when popup is open add this

```
map.on('popupopen', function (){ //map is the name of map you gave to your leaflet map
  $('.classoflabels').addClass('hidden');
})
map.on('popupclose', function (){ //map is the name of map you gave to your leaflet map
  $('.classoflabels').removeClass('hidden');
})
```

hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the labels with removeLayer(label) when the popup appears and add them to map again when it closes.